# React component w/ singe child => Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I encountered a problem in React that leaves me puzzled.

I want to create Component that's basically a wrapper around its children. Let's say a simple Button component.

```
<Button {...props} circular radius="small">
  <Icon type="close" />
</Button>
```

When doing so I obtain the following error:

```
Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
    at http://localhost:9009/static/preview.bundle.js:2027:45
    at Array.map (native)
    at objToCss (http://localhost:9009/static/preview.bundle.js:2025:30)
    at http://localhost:9009/static/preview.bundle.js:2026:33
    at Array.map (native)
    at objToCss (http://localhost:9009/static/preview.bundle.js:2025:30)
    at http://localhost:9009/static/preview.bundle.js:2050:42
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at flatten (http://localhost:9009/static/preview.bundle.js:2033:17)
    at http://localhost:9009/static/preview.bundle.js:2045:63
```

Yet, and this is the *crazy part*, when I render more than one child, i.e. children, then **it magically works**.

```
<Button {...props} circular radius="small">
  <Icon type="close" />
  <Icon type="close" />
</Button>
```

=> no error

What in the world is going on? Why is React trying to convert my React element, which it first wraps into a symbol, into a string? What are Symbols anyways? If someone could enlighten me that would be awesome:) For now I render an empty `<span />` to circumvent the problem.

i.e.

```
<Button {...props} circular radius="small">
  <Icon type="close" />
  <span />
</Button>
```

---

Right now this is my `<Button />` component. I know I could directly export just the RawButton. But what I want to be doing later on is to compose components. Currently, I only get it to run by rendering at least 2 children. I do not understand how rendering a single child causes this problem-.-

```
const RawButton = styled.button`
  border-radius: ${props => (props.circular ? '50%' : BORDER_RADIUS)};
`;

export default (props) =>
  <RawButton {...props}>
    <span />
    {props.children}
  </RawButton>
```

Comment: Is button your custom component and what all objects are there in props

Comment: I would like to see the render method for `<Button/>`-component.
Hopefully you try to render `children` even if you know that `children` consists of one child.

Comment: ok I need to give you the full picture. I am using styled-components. Into the Wrapper I am passing the `circular` and `radius` props and inside the component I am rendering `props.children`.

Comment: From the error trace it looks like when `styled-components` tries to construct CSS string from objects, it encountered a Symbol variable (if you don't know Symbol, it's basically a more efficient constant that cannot be converted to string.

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/59274bd7fc8f44321577dd78ba4f10b71bb24a09/src/utils/flatten.js#L10

Comment: I just experimented and realized it is a problem that stems from styled-components. Without it, it just renders fine. But why is it ok with multiple symbols but struggles when I pass it a single one?

Comment: @soosap can you show me the render method of your Button component?

Comment: @VivekN just appended the render method of the Button component. It's a stateless functional component

Comment: @soosap I tried the code myself and it worked for me for both the scenarios.
Would you like to screen share?It will help me better understand the problem.

Comment: Hey thanks @VivekN offering your help. You motivated me to try out on my own before. I was then able to track down the problem to a prop inside my RawButton that I set via Ramda. I was making incorrect use of Ramda's curry function. Problem solved :) Thanks everyone.

Comment: @soosap great. Happy to help always.. :)